# Django CreateView without template rendering

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a problem with saving a form in my CreateView, I found
this solution and it worked for me:

```
class ScheduleDocumentView(CreateView):

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ScheduleDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.relates_to = Schedule.objects.get(pk=pk)
            form.save()
        return redirect('planning:schedule-detail', pk=pk)
```

However my goal is to save a form using form_valid() and get_success_url() without a template in CreateView. I tried something like this(doesn't work):

```
class ScheduleDocumentView(CreateView):
    model = ScheduleDocument
    form_class = ScheduleDocumentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.relates_to = Schedule.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form.save()
        return redirect('planning:schedule-detail', pk=pk)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('planning:schedule-detail', kwargs={'pk': pk})
```

It requires a template, is there any other way to handle my post request in DetailView, process it in separate CreateView and redirect it to my DetailView page?

Here's my template for DetailView:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'planning:upload-document' schedule.pk %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="button button--secondary">Attach</button>
```

Urls:

```
path('schedules/<int:pk>/', ScheduleDetailView.as_view(), name='schedule-detail'),
path('schedules/<int:pk>/upload-document/', ScheduleDocumentView.as_view(), name='upload-document'),
```

**I came across this solution:**

```
class ScheduleDocumentView(CreateView):
    model = ScheduleDocument
    form_class = ScheduleDocumentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.schedule = Schedule.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('planning:schedule-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is a 'solution' (re: 'I came across this solution...'  above)? It's nearly identical to your previous code, and it's not clear to a reader, such as myself, why or how this solves the initial problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`template_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name) is required [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name):

> The full name of a template to use as defined by a string. Not
> defining a template_name will raise a
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured exception.

Or in your case **Django** would cause the default **template_name** to be `'yourapp/scheduledocument_create_form.html'`.

Therefore you get the error `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

You can get the `pk` value from [**`self.kwargs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)[(Django Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view).

You can simple create the **blank.html** template.

```
class ScheduleDocumentView(CreateView):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    template_name = 'blank.html' # or use this 'schedule_detail.html'
    model = ScheduleDocument
    form_class = ScheduleDocumentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.relates_to = Schedule.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('planning:schedule-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get("pk")})
```

Or use [**A simple view**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view):

```
def create_schedule_document(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScheduleDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.relates_to = Schedule.objects.get(pk=pk)
            obj.save()
    else:
        form = ApplyAnonymousForm()
    return redirect('planning:schedule-detail', pk=pk)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've already tried exactly the same lines of code, but it still displays the error TemplateDoesNotExist, seems like template is being rendered before form_valid and get_success_url methods.

Comment: Or you can also create a blank template: `blank.html`. And using it in any other view. Or create **A simple view**. I updated my answer.

Comment: OMG, it worked! blank.html helped me to debug it. I realised my problem was in form validation. Thank you!

Comment: If the actual problem was in form validation, could you clarify somewhere here what was happening and what led to the solution? I'm having the same issue (TemplateDoesNotExist error when using CreateView without a template) but I can not deduce the solution from what you have provided in this post.

Comment: @m.arthur , as you can see in my answer `template_name` is required. Django `CreateView` has a method `get_template_names()` - where Django try to get a template, based on `app_label`, `model_name ` and `template_name_suffix` you can see it [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/). Please ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to get more detailed answer.

Comment: @ NKSM you're incorrect on that point, though. I have multiple CreateView and UpdateView classes I'm using without templates. template_name is not absolutely required. you can leave it out and make post requests to the view. it's only required if you need to make a GET request to the view. I solved this by changing the form submission to POST. When you do this, the error does not occur, and you can run the view just for the POST (form submission) behavior.